# How many real numbers satisfy $ x + x^{-1} $ so that it is a Whole number.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, real-numbers, fractions

I came across this in a discrete mathematics book, and i wonder if my solution is correct.

From looking at $ y = x + x^{-1} $

I see only 2 possibilities,  x ={1;-1;}

Was this just 
so easy or am I missing something?

Comment: It's certainly not 0,  $0^{-1}$ is undefined

Comment: Are you trying to determine what is the range of $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$ with $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ ?

Comment: If we only allow $x\in\Bbb Z$, then yes, there are only 2 possibilities $(1,-1)$. This is because $x+\frac 1x\in\Bbb Z\iff x\mid x^2+1\implies x\mid 1\implies x\in\{-1,1\}$

Comment: But since you mention $x\in\Bbb R$, there exist solutions for all $x+\frac 1x=k\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ by the IVT property of continuous functions.

Comment: "I see only 2 possibilities, x ={1;-1;} "  How do you know there aren't any more.  Proving that there are not, or finding more.  Is where the trick is.  And others have pointed out the trick is solving $x+x^{-1} = k$ is solving $x^2 -kx + 1=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any integer $n$ we want $n=x+\frac 1x\iff x^2-nx+1=0$

We need $\Delta=n^2-4\ge 0$ for the above equation to have solutions, so $|n|\ge 2$.

And the solutions are $x=\dfrac{n\pm\sqrt{n^2-4}}2$ (note that $x^{-1}=\dfrac{n\mp\sqrt{n^2-4}}2$ in that case).

For $n=2$ you get the $(1,1)$ solution

For $n=-2$ you get $(-1,-1)$ solution

For $n=4$ you get the nice $(2+\sqrt{3},2-\sqrt{3})$ solution

and so on ...

Comment: In other words, *infinitely many*, no?

Comment: yes, a countable bunch of them. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Let $$x+\frac{1}{x}=k$$

$$x^2+1=kx$$

This is a quadratic equation. For which values of $k$ does this has a real solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowing $x\in \mathbb R$, you get a lot more solutions, an infinite number in fact.  Saying it is a whole number is saying that there exists an $m$, whole number, such that $$x+x^{-1}=m$$
Following this, we have
$$m=x+\frac 1 x=\frac {x^2 +1} x$$

so $$x^2+1=mx$$
 or $$x^2-mx+1=0$$
For this to have solutions,  we can just turn to the quadratic formula

$$x=\frac {m \pm \sqrt {m^2 -4}} {2} $$
Thus, we get solutions whenever $$m^2\ge 4$$
restricting to whole numbers, this gives us when $$m\ge 2$$

For example,  choosing $m=3$ and the $+$ solution gets us to

$$x=\frac {3+\sqrt 5} 2$$

so $$x+x^{-1}=\frac {3+\sqrt 5} 2+\frac 2 {3 +\sqrt 5}=\frac {9+6\sqrt 5+5+4}{6+2\sqrt 5}=\frac {18+6\sqrt 5}{6+2\sqrt 5}=3$$

This will work for the - as well,  not to mention any whole number 2 or higher.

Comment: $m^2 \ge 4 \implies m \ge 2$ hmmm, i disagree